# Java game programming: multiple instances of an object, treat same way?

Tags: java, coding-style

Sorry if the title didn't make much sense. I'm making a Chip's Challenge style game in Java Eclipse where special things like the Player, coins, and pushable blocks are a class. Interactions between the pushable block and the player require a lot of collision detection logic, and the code is getting atrocious because I have to do the same logic checks for each instance of the class. For example:

```
public void pb1TouchingBaddy() {

    if (pb1.getTileX() == b1.getTileX() & pb1.getTileY() == b1.getTileY()) {
        if (b1.getbUp() == 1 & pb1.getTileY() - 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, -1);
        } else if (b1.getbDown() == 1
                & pb1.getTileY() + 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, 1);
        } else if (b1.getbRight() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() + 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(1, 0);
        } else if (b1.getbLeft() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() - 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(-1, 0);
        }
    }

    if (pb1.getTileX() == b2.getTileX() & pb1.getTileY() == b2.getTileY()) {
        if (b2.getbUp() == 1 & pb1.getTileY() - 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, -1);
        } else if (b2.getbDown() == 1
                & pb1.getTileY() + 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, 1);
        } else if (b2.getbRight() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() + 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(1, 0);
        } else if (b2.getbLeft() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() - 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(-1, 0);
        }
    }

    if (pb1.getTileX() == b3.getTileX() & pb1.getTileY() == b3.getTileY()) {
        if (b3.getbUp() == 1 & pb1.getTileY() - 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, -1);
        } else if (b3.getbDown() == 1
                & pb1.getTileY() + 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, 1);
        } else if (b3.getbRight() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() + 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(1, 0);
        } else if (b3.getbLeft() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() - 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(-1, 0);
        }
    }

    if (pb1.getTileX() == b4.getTileX() & pb1.getTileY() == b4.getTileY()) {
        if (b4.getbUp() == 1 & pb1.getTileY() - 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, -1);
        } else if (b4.getbDown() == 1
                & pb1.getTileY() + 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, 1);
        } else if (b4.getbRight() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() + 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(1, 0);
        } else if (b4.getbLeft() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() - 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(-1, 0);
        }
    }
```

So as you can see those three blocks of if statements are all the exact same logic, just applied to different instances of the same object. Is there any way  to write this without having to repeat myself so much? I was able to turn the four directional movement logic into one method and thought I was a genius for a while, but I can't figure out how to do a similar thing  but  with multiple instances of the same object. Right now I'm stuck with just two of the pushable blocks before I get too confused and can't do the logic for another one. Would appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Write a method that takes an instance of the whatever object `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, and `b4` are, and perform the checks that way.

Comment: So there's some way to pass the instance of an object into a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private function move(PBClass pb1, PBClass pb2, BClass b) {
    if (pb1.getTileX() == b.getTileX() & pb1.getTileY() == b.getTileY()) {
        if (b.getbUp() == 1 & pb1.getTileY() - 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, -1);
        } else if (b.getbDown() == 1
                & pb1.getTileY() + 1 != pb2.getTileY()) {
            pb1.move(0, 1);
        } else if (b.getbRight() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() + 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(1, 0);
        } else if (b.getbLeft() == 1
                & pb1.getTileX() - 1 != pb2.getTileX()) {
            pb1.move(-1, 0);
        }
    }
}

public void pb1TouchingBaddy() {
    move(pb1, pb2, b1);
    move(pb1, pb2, b2);
    move(pb1, pb2, b3);
    move(pb1, pb2, b4);
}
```

of course you'll need to replace `PBClass` and `BClass` with your actual class names.

If you have an array of objects:

```
PBClass[] listPB = { pb1, pb2, pb3, pb4};
BClass[] listB = { b1, b2, b3, b4};

public void pb1TouchingBaddy() {
    for (int i=0; i < listPB.length - 1; i+=2) {
        for (int j=0; j < listB.length; j++) {
            move(pb[i], pb[i+1], b[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use `ArrayList`s in the same way

Comment: I meant I want some way where I don't have to write "pb1" "pb2" etc every time. So I could technically have instances going up to "pb100" and not have to write pb59, pb60, pb61, etc. anywhere.

Comment: are your `pb`s in a list? what about the `b`s is there only four of them?

Comment: My apologies, pretty sure this completely answered my question. Was just too daft to realize you had reduced my code by 1/3 in size :D Thank you! Going to try implementing this system and see if the game still behaves the same, many thanks!

Comment: Helped a ton, here's what I ended up with, awesome how much smaller the project is getting: EDIT: okay can't add that much to this lil box take my word for it though!

Answer (score 2):

Put those methods in an interface and make them all implement that interface.

Make your method to be interested only in that interface, not worring about what the actual concrete types could be.

Answer (score 2):

You'll require some sort of `Iterable` collection. That way you'd be able to loop through it.

Comment: But I still have to write pb1, pb2, pb3, etc? I can't just do pbX and pass in X? I can do something like what you've written but that's not the problem I'm having. I just wnat to generalize the object code so the player will treat all instances of the object the same way without me having to say so explicitly for each instance and add 5 billion lines of code.

Comment: You'll need loops. Create a class that implements `Iterable` or have some sort of `Iterator`. Or use some subclass of [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Comment: Sorry man your code answer actually helped a lot I just didn't realize what it was doing. Going to give that style a try, thank you! Going to look into Collections too, much appreciated.